# Is it possibile in node execute a function in a particular time?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new about nodejs and I'm tring to execute a function in a particular time. Node working with eventi-driven paradigma so I'm tring to do something linke this:

```
executeFutureFunction(function(),timestamp);
```

`function()` : is my function()

`timestamp`: is the timestamp when the function() is executed.

I don't want use setTimeout, in my case is not a correct solution.Anyone can help me?

Comment: "in my case is not a correct solution" — This is too vague. Why are you ruling it out? Any other suggested solution might have the same problem.

Comment: What are you asking here? You say you have a function that sets a timeout, but you can't use it? And how do you want to set a timeout without `setTimeout`?

Comment: Of course `setTimeout` is the correct solution. You just need to change how you're thinking about it. Take your desired execution time (`timestamp` in your example code) and subtract the current time from it. That will give you the "delay" between now and then which you can pass to `setTimeout`.

Comment: If I use setTimeout if I restar server, I lose timeout

Comment: @JoePeteny If you restart your server, you'll lose everything running in the JS runtime. You'll have to save off the desired start time to a file somewhere and load it in when you start the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule package to achieve this. Example from the documentation:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
    console.log('The world is going to end today.');
});
```